# Duplicate new google calendar event to another calendar with google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a script so when I create an event in one google calendar it automatically duplicates the event in another google calendar. I have tried using the code below (swapping Calendar IDs with my own - assuming I use the full ID e.g. xyz@group.google etc):

```
function myFunction() {
var calendarSource = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarID");
var calendarDestination = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarID");
var eventToCopy = calendarSource.getEvents(new Date("July 21, 2009 EST"), new Date("July 22, 2009 EST"));

//read up: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_recurrence
var newRecurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().times(10);

for (var i in eventToCopy){
if (eventToCopy[i].getTitle() == "event name"){
  var newEvent = calendarDestination.createEventSeries(eventToCopy[i].getTitle(), eventToCopy[i].getStartTime(), eventToCopy[i].getEndTime(), newRecurrence);
}

}
```

Nothing seems to happen though. Anyone give me a headstart? I only want this to trigger on creation of a NEW event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I copy (duplicate) a calendar event into another calendar using Google Script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497158/how-can-i-copy-duplicate-a-calendar-event-into-another-calendar-using-google-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code snippet you posted, events are only copied to the new calendar if their title equals "event name" due to the line `if (eventToCopy[i].getTitle() == "event name"){`. The events you have in your source calendar probably don't have this title, so nothing is being copied. You should be able to remove this `if` condition to get all events to copy.

```
function myFunction() {
  var calendarSource = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarID");
  var calendarDestination = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarID");
  var eventToCopy = calendarSource.getEvents(new Date("July 21, 2009 EST"), new Date("July 22, 2009 EST"));

  //read up: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_recurrence
  var newRecurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().times(10);

  for (var i in eventToCopy){
    var newEvent = calendarDestination.createEventSeries(eventToCopy[i].getTitle(), eventToCopy[i].getStartTime(), eventToCopy[i].getEndTime(), newRecurrence);
  }
}
```