# How to Read Calendar Event Recurrence Settings Using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-calendar-recurring-events

I can't seem to figure out a way how to read recurrence settings of an `CalendarEventSeries` using Google Apps Script.

There is a [`setRecurrence`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series#setrecurrencerecurrence-startdate) method; I am looking for something like `getRecurrence` hoping it would return an [`EventRecurrence`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-recurrence) object representing the recurrence settings of an [`EventSeries`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series).

Any ideas?

---

Why do I need this? I simply want to copy an event from one calendar to another, keeping the recurrence settings (if any).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I copy (duplicate) a calendar event into another calendar using Google Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497158/how-can-i-copy-duplicate-a-calendar-event-into-another-calendar-using-google-s)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Calendar API instead of the builtin calendar library.
The API exposes much more information.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances

Comment: Java, Python, PHP, Ruby ... I prefer using JavaScript and Google Apps Script as this includes variety of triggers for firing the script from the cloud. With Calendar API I would have to obtain my own server and set some sort of time trigger to fire the script (which is a lot more work), am I right?

Comment: No...not at all. You need to enable the api  service from "Resources>Advanced Google Service" (in the script editor), then go to the developer console and enable the Calendar API and you can use the API from within your google script. No Server/PHP/Ruby required. Also...refresh your script window after enabling these...sometimes the auto complete function doesn't kick in until a refresh. Once you have refreshed, in your editor, type "Calendar." (with a capital C and a period) and the available properties/methods will show up in the code hint dropdown.

Comment: Alright, I enabled Calendar API in both script menu Resources... and from the Developer Console. I successfully ran the [JavaScipt Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) from my localhost; however I still have no idea how to run it from the documents cloud using Google Apps Script :-(

Comment: This should help...Here is a quickstart page for using the API in google apps script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar