# Get recurrence of CalendarEvent in G-Suite Addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-recurring-events, gsuite-addons

I'm working on a Google Calendar addon that synchronizes event data with an external service. It's easy to get data like title, description, dates etc. of an event and I can even check wether it's a recurring event or not with `event.isRecurringEvent()`.

What I can't seem to find out is how to get the recurrence rule(s) for a specific event. Is this even possible? Neither https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event nor https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series have something like `getRecurrenceRule()`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What about [getEventSeries()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getEventSeries())?

Comment: @Casper, that returns an array of events (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series.html). No getRecurrenceRule or similar either

Comment: Perhaps try with API as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770235/how-to-read-calendar-event-recurrence-settings-using-google-apps-script)

Comment: Cheers @Casper! I'll give that a try! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a [CalendarEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event) in Google Apps Script and you want to get its recurrence.

Since, as you said, there is not a method like `getRecurrenceRule()`, you will have to activate the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) and call [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) to get information on the recurrence of the event. If `event` is your `CalendarEvent`, you can retrieve the information on the recurrence by doing the following:

```js
eventId = event.getId().split("@")[0];
var eventFromAPI = Calendar.Events.get(calId, eventId);
var recurrence = eventFromAPI["recurrence"];
return recurrence;
```

#### Notes:

- I'm using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to remove the characters after `@` of the string returned by `event.getId()`, because it appends `@google.com`.
- The `recurrence` is a "list of RRULE, EXRULE, RDATE and EXDATE lines for a recurring event, as specified in [RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5)". Even though this has information of the recurrence of the event, it's not an instance of the Apps Script class [RecurrenceRule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/recurrence-rule). As far as I know, there is no way to return that.

#### Reference:

- [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar)
- [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get)
- [Calendar API: Event resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)
- [RecurrenceRule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/recurrence-rule)

I hope this is of any help.